# <JAVASCRIPT/JSP> How to make function for radio-button and search-bar with select-option

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a radio box and search-bar with a select box with two option values.

```
<td>
    <label for="requireDate"><input type="radio" id="date" value="requireDate" name="date" checked="checked"/>START DATE</label>
    <label for="finishDate"><input type="radio" id="date" value="finishDate" name="date" />END DATE</label>
</td>
 . . . 
<tr>
<th>search word</th>
<td>    
    <select name="selectOp" id="selectOp">
        <option value="clipNo">CLIP NUMBER</option>
        <option value="tapeNo">TAPE NUMBER</option>
    </select>
    <span class="br">
        <input type="text" id="searchWord" name="searchWord"/>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Based on this code, two different Ajax function will be called when clicked on **SEARCH** button. I got the part done where it functions based on radio button.

But when it adds the function with search bar with two select options, I can't figure it out how to do it.

Following is the part I got it done with Radio button selection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').click(function() {         

if($(':radio[name=date]:checked').val() == 'requireDate'){ 
            CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/encodeMng/encodeListAjaxSubscDtm" />', 1, $('#frm').serialize(), 'content');        
        } else if($(':radio[name=date]:checked').val() == 'finishDate'){ 
            CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/encodeMng/encodeListAjaxcpltSubscDt" />', 1, $('#frm').serialize(), 'content');             
        }           
});
</script>
```

For instance, if I select the radio button with "**requireDate**", then **clip number** in the option, then write "777" in **search bar** then click on the **search** button.

Then it should show a data that has "777" in its clip number that was called by radio button with  "**requireDate**".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('#date').val()
```

do:

```
$(':radio[name=date]:checked').val()
```

that's it.

The problem is that your old query always got the first radiobutton, no mattering if it was selected or not.

Cheers

Comment: I edited the question code like your answer. So this will cover not only radio button value, but select button and search word as well??